# highcharts: bubble charts: can I render the bubbles higher, not centered?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am roughly familiar with bubble charts from highcharts.
Bubbles are always rendered centered dependant to its X and Y coordinates.

Imagine the Y-Axis is currency(dollars). A bubble costs e.g. 100 dollars.
Then the bubble gets rendered exactly in the middle of these 100 dollars (and X-Axis) and ranges for example with its margin to 110 dollars on top and 90 dollars on the bottom depending on its radius of course.

Now, is there a way to set this bubble artificially higher that exactly the bottom of the edge stripes the 100 dollar mark?

Of course I can manipulate all the data series by adding an offset of 10 dollars. But that does not work if I use "zoom-function" because the scale differs then!

If someone wants to know why I need this strange stuff:
There should not be room to negotiate if article "xyz" costs 100 dollars and the bubble ranges down to 90. The buyer should not get the idea he could negotiate the prize because there is space to 90 dollars because of its radius!

Hey thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported, byut you can extend default method `drawPoints`: http://jsfiddle.net/zb443xj9/

```
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.bubble.prototype, 'drawPoints', function (p) {
        var series = this;
        H.each(series.points, function (point, i) {
            point.shapeArgs.y -= point.shapeArgs.r; // move center up by radius
        });

        p.call(this);
    });
})(Highcharts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is definitely an approach! Very nice!

Within the bubbles I hold information like X-value and Y-value.

I can simply move the ***dataLabels*** back to the new bubble using 
y: -35, //hard coded value -35 suits in my case, can I also access to the radius here?

I'd like to have sth like:

```
y: -point.shapeArgs.r //how can I access to this property?
```

Here the code extract for the ***dataLabels***:

```
plotOptions: {
        bubble: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                y: -35,
                style: { textShadow: 'none' },
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.point.y + "<br>" + this.point.x ;
                }
            },
            minSize: '10%',
            maxSize: '30%'
        }
    },
```

The last problem is the ***Tooltip***.
Tooltip still refers to original center.
You can see that, if you hover over the now shifted bubble.
You see the "old original" shadow.

Can we add / modify your function that it suits for Tooltip as well?

Regards!